# How do I reliably find a request's referrer in a firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon

I've found the referrer attribute on `nsIHttpChannel` and this works most of the time but this is only set subject to certain security checks (e.g. it won't be set if you're navigating from an HTTPS to an HTTP URL).

I can see that it's possible to get the load context (`nsILoadContext`) and, through that, things like the associated window but I can't find a way of finding the referrer information through these.

So my question is this; for those requests which have a referring URL but which don't pass the security checks present on the `nsIHttpChannel` referrer attribute, is there a way of obtaining the referrer information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gecko saves the referrer in the `docshell.internalReferrer` property even in the cases where the `Referer` header isn't sent. In most cases you should be able to read out referrer information like this:

```
if (channel instanceof nsIPropertyBag)
{
  try
  {
    referrer = channel.getProperty("docshell.internalReferrer");
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    // Internal referrer not set, fall back to the Referer header
    referrer = channel.referrer;
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks useful but an nsIHttpChannel is not an nsIPropertyBag; how do I find the properties when all I have is the channel?

Comment: @goodwinster: It is. HTTP and FTP channels always implement the `nsIPropertyBag` interface. Note that I used `instanceof` operator because [it will implicitly call `QueryInterface()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/instanceof#Mozilla_developers).

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.A note for others wanting to do the same, the URI returned may use the wyciwyg scheme; you'll need to infer the original URI if you want to use this for host checking, etc.